# Homeomorphism between real projective plane and disc

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $D = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ \|\mathbf{x}\| \le 1\}$ and let $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ be the real projective plane Let $X = D/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies antipodal points in the boundary of $D$. I am interested in finding explicitly a homeomorphism between X and the projective plane. Could anyone please help me with this one?

Comment: The question doesn't match the title: $D$ is a disc, not a sphere.

Comment: But they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: What would be your definition of the projective plane?

Comment: I'm guessing his definition is the space of lines through the origin.  Even still, you can't use $D$ to make this construction.  Try $S^2 / \sim$.  The $0$ will screw you over otherwise.

Comment: This $D$ looks alright and it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^2$, but still neither of them is a sphere.

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191420

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, if $D$ is a 2-dimensional closed ball and $X = D / \sim$, where $\sim$ identifies antipodal points on the boundary, then there is a homeomorphism $\varphi \colon X \to \mathbb{R}P^2$. Here is how we define it:
$$
\varphi(x,y) = x:y:\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}
$$
where $(x,y)$ are coordinates of a point in $D$. Notice that if $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$ then $\varphi(x,y)=\varphi(x',y')$, so $\varphi$ is well defined. You can check yourself that this is a homeomorphism.

Basically, what I've done here is compose the natural homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}P^2 \to (S^2 / \approx)$, where $\approx$ identifies antipodal points on the sphere, with a homeomorphism $(S^2 / \approx) \to X$ which simply projects the upper half-sphere to the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the notation $x:y:\sqrt{1 -x^2 -y^2}$? What does it indicate?

Comment: @Stefan These are [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) on the projective plane.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps what you want is that $\Bbb RP^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^n/\sim$ where we say $x\sim y$ if $y=tx$ for some $t\in \Bbb R$ (we're identifying antipodal points). You can check that a homeomorhism is induced by the map $$f(x)=\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}.$$

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: No, what he wants is exactly what he asked...

Comment: @ChrisGerig: See Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds* on Exercise 7.11 from Chapter 2. The exercise explicitly asks us to show that this map induces a homemorphism, where, in this case $$\overline{f}\big([x]\big)=\left[\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}\right].$$

Comment: @Clayton Why is the function f continuous? $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\rightarrow{S^{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

They aren't homeomorphic.  You can look at their homology to see this.  (There is probably an easier way, this seems like overkill).

Edit:  And yes, as a commenter has pointed out, the $D$ you described is a closed ball, and this is contractible so that's not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ either

Comment: There is, they have different Euler characteristics, plus $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is not orientable.

Comment: One is a boundaryless manifold, another is not.

Comment: @muzzlator: Show me the homology calculation, because I disagree with you. Sanchez: Neither has boundary, my friend.  Anyway, you start with $S^n/\sim$ and this is the same as the upper-hemisphere with antipodal points on the equator identified (and this is his "disk"!)

Comment: @Chris When this answer was posted the question looked quite a bit different. Back then it was about the projective plane on one hand and either a sphere or a closed ball on the other hand.

Comment: Ah makes sense now!