# Why is $D^n/\sim$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $D^n$ (the $n$-dimensional unit disc) which identifies antipodal points on the boundary $\partial D^n = S^{n-1}$. Show that $D^n/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^n$, the real projective space of dimension $n$.

**Edit:** We define $\mathbb{RP}^n$ as the set of real lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, with the origin deleted, with the quotient topology determined by the map which sends a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ to the line containing it.

Comment: but you didn't specify the topology.

Comment: can you think of a function from the set of lines you describe to the set of pairs of points in $D^n$? (hint: intersection). Are these points always antipodal (hint: yes). What does that tell you?

Comment: The function which sends a line (in, say, $\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\}$) to its intersection with $\partial D^n$, which is a pair of antipodal points in $D^n$. I'm still thinking about what this tells you.

Comment: I'm not sure what it tells you. Can you say what it tells you about?

Comment: it tells *you* that you should review what quotient spaces are.

Comment: I'm confused about what happens with the points in the interior of $D^n$.

Comment: Remember also: $$P({\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}}) = \mathbb{R}{P^n}$$
Lines are coming from ${\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}}$

Answer (score 1):

Take these local coordinates, to proof ${D^{n + 1}} \simeq P{\mathbb{R}^n}$
\begin{gathered}
  {U_i} = \{ \left. {[{x_0}, \cdots ,{x_n}]} \right|{x_i} \ne 0\}  \subset P({\mathbb{R}^{n + 1}}) \hfill \\
  {\varphi _i}:{U_i} \to {\mathbb{R}^n},[{x_0}, \cdots ,{x_n}] \to (\frac{{{x_0}}}{{{x_i}}}, \cdots ,\frac{{{x_{i - 1}}}}{{{x_i}}},\frac{{{x_{i + 1}}}}{{{x_i}}}, \cdots ,\frac{{{x_n}}}{{{x_i}}}) \hfill \\
  {\psi _i}:{\mathbb{R}^n} \to {U_i},({a_1}, \cdots ,{a_n}) \to [{a_1}, \cdots ,{a_{i - 1}},1,{a_i}, \cdots ,{a_n}] \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is too late but the statement is proved by first considering $\mathbb{R}P^{n}\cong S^{n}/C_{2}$, where $C_{2}$ acts on $S^{n}$ by identifying antipodal points.

Now, if we only consider the upper hemisphere of $S^{n}$, this is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ and is also homeomorphic to $D^{n}/\sim$, since the boundary of $D^{n}$, namely $S^{n-1}$, is the equator of the previous n-sphere $S^{n}$ and the equivalence relation remains there.