# Homeomorphism between N-disk and N-Projective Plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I've just showed that:
$D^n$, quotiented with this equivalence relation:

$x\sim y \iff x=-y \text{ and } x,y\in\partial D^n$

(i.e. the antipodal points on the boundary of $D^n$ are identified)

is homeomorphic to $RP^n$.
for $n=3$

Just for curiosity, could be that extended for every $n$ ?

thank you so much in Advance for any hints !!

Comment: @StefanHamcke I forgot to write a piece of the problem indeed. Now there's written all

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**yes.**

First of all, it is easy to see that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^n/\langle x\sim -x\rangle$ (pretty standard exercise you can find anywhere).

Now it remains to be proved that $$S^n/\langle x\sim -x\rangle \cong D^n/\sim' $$ (The quotient you mention.

Take the map which sends $[x] \in S^n$ to $x$ where $x$ is the representative of the class $[x]$ which lies in the upper hemisphere. You possibly have only problem if $[x]$ is such that $x$ (and so $-x$) lies on the equator. You don't have a canonical choice for them, but in the target space you claim that both choice are the same point, therefore any choice works fine and therefore you are done. Continuity is clear and bicontinuity as well.