# Prove $(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\})/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$

Tags: general-topology

I am very new to the concepts about quotient topology so I have no idea how to correctly show $(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$. Here the equivalence relation is defined as $x\sim kx$ if $k>0$.

Comment: This is a bit wrong. [Better formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191420/why-is-dn-sim-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrpn?rq=1).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $D^n/\sim$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191420/why-is-dn-sim-homeomorphic-to-mathbbrpn)

Comment: @KurtG. the equivalence relation is $x \sim kx$ for all positive $k$, not all $k \neq 0$ (which would result in the quotient space being $\mathbb{RP}^n$).

Answer (score 2):

Let us observe that each retraction $\rho : X \to Y \subset X$ (i.e. each continuous map with $\rho \mid_Y = id_Y$) is a quotient map. This holds  true because $\rho$ is surjective and if $U \subset Y$ is a subset such that  $\rho^{-1}(U)$ open in $X$, then $U = \rho^{-1}(U) \cap Y$ is open in $Y$.

It is well-known that for each quotient map $q : Z \to Z'$ the induced map
$$\bar q : Z/\sim_q \to Z', \bar q([x]) = q(x)$$
is a homeomorphism, where $\sim_q$ is the equivalence relation defined by  $z_1 \sim_q z_2$ iff $q(z_1) = q(z_2)$.

Now define $r : \mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to S^n, r(x) = x/\lVert x \rVert$. This is a retraction. The equivalence relations $\sim$ and $\sim_r$ are identical because

1. $r(kx) = r(x)$ for $k > 0$.
2. $r(x) = r(x')$ means  $x' = kx$ with $k = \lVert x' \rVert/ \lVert x \rVert > 0$.

This answers your question in the affirmative.